# how to call files with createBlock

Tags: magento

I am following No_Frills_Magento_Layout by Alan Storm. I have got to a point that I could not make work by following what the book said so I went about it an alternate way

Below is the books way and I get an error

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton(’core/layout’);
$block = $layout->createBlock('ts_nofrills/helloworld', 'root');
echo $block->toHtml();

//Fatal error: Call to a member function createBlock() on a non-object in
```

below is my way and produces the .phtml text

```
$main_block = new Ts_Nofrills_Block_Helloworld();
$layout = Mage::getSingleton(’core/layout’);
$block = $layout->createBlock($main_block, 'root');
echo $block->toHtml();
```

My problem is as the book continues this example  is expanded on and by deviating from the example and doing it my way I dont feel like I am learning to the full potential.

I guess I have written the first parameter incorrectly for magento to recognise it in the createBlock function what have i done wrong on example one?

I have been reluctant to put this question on for two reasons:

1 - Im sure the answer is in the book (I cant find it though)

2 - Im sure this question has been asked on here (once again I have looked but cant find it)

===EDIT===

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <Ts_Nofrills>
            <class>Ts_Nofrills_Block</class>
        </Ts_Nofrills>
    </blocks>
  ....
</global>
```

file structure

- Ts
- - Nofrills
- - - Block
- - - - Template.php
- - - controllers
- - - - IndexController.php
- - - etc
- - - - config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside etc/config.xml in the global node you should have:

```
<blocks>
        <ts_nofrills>
            <class>Ts_Nofrills_Block</class>
        </ts_nofrills>
</blocks>
```

When you want to create a block using php or layout xml you have to use the value from the node etc/config.xml blocks as namespace followed by `/` and then the path to your file inside the module delimited by underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the reply to my question. I do have the config setup which is why example two produce my .phtml file. What I dont understand is why example one produces and error and not example two. If it was a config problem surly they would both produce an error?

Comment: No, they would not produce an error since in your example you are creating a new object and in Alan's he is using Magento to create that object. I believe that in your case, Magento doesn't know from where to get the block class because of the config.

Comment: To load your class `ts_nofrills/helloworld` Magento looks in the config.xml for the first part whre are block classes called `ts_nofrills` and should find `Ts_Nofrills_Block` and then `/` becomes `_` and and explode for `_` and `ucfirst` for every element in the explode array so the class becomes `Ts_Nofrills_Block_Helloworld` and shoud be found inside `app/code/local/Ts/Nofrills/Block/Helloworld.php`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Maybe i've been staring at this problem for to long and now cant see the problem even though its staring me in the face. I have edit my original question to add my file structure and config to see if it will help with an answer

Comment: Try to not use capital letters, look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks Emi I have looked at your answer and thats how I understood it to work, which still leaves me confused as to why this doesn't work, I have tried making the caps lowercase

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35925/discussion-between-emi-and-tony09uk)